# How do I use Iterator's #map with #fold in rust?

Tags: iterator, rust

`rustc 0.13.0-nightly (f168c12c5 2014-10-25 20:57:10 +0000)`

I have the following code.

```
fn main() {
  let nums = vec![1i,2,3];

  let strings = nums.iter()
  .map(|n| n.to_string())
  .fold(String::new, |a, b| a.push_str(b.as_slice()));

  assert_eq!("123", strings.as_slice());
}
```

It should convert the integers in nums to their string representations and join them to one big String.

Here's what I get from rustc:

```
test2.rs:6:31: 6:53 error: type `fn() -> collections::string::String` does not implement any method in scope named `push_str`
test2.rs:6   .fold(String::new, |a, b| a.push_str(b.as_slice()));
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test2.rs:8:29: 8:39 error: type `fn() -> collections::string::String` does not implement any method in scope named `as_slice`
test2.rs:8   assert_eq!("123", strings.as_slice());
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:6:23: 6:33 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
<std macros>:6                 if !((*given_val == *expected_val) &&
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:1:1: 14:2 note: in expansion of assert_eq!
test2.rs:8:3: 8:41 note: expansion site
<std macros>:6:23: 6:33 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
<std macros>:6                 if !((*given_val == *expected_val) &&
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:1:1: 14:2 note: in expansion of assert_eq!
test2.rs:8:3: 8:41 note: expansion site
<std macros>:6:37: 6:50 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
<std macros>:6                 if !((*given_val == *expected_val) &&
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:1:1: 14:2 note: in expansion of assert_eq!
test2.rs:8:3: 8:41 note: expansion site
<std macros>:7:23: 7:36 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
<std macros>:7                      (*expected_val == *given_val)) {
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:1:1: 14:2 note: in expansion of assert_eq!
test2.rs:8:3: 8:41 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to 6 previous errors
```

So it complains about the type `fn() -> collections::string::String`, but I was expecting the result of the map to be just a plain `collections::string::String`.

Did I do anything wrong here, or is map not supposed to be used like I tried it in the example?

**EDIT:**

haha ok I found the mistake, `String::new` is a `fn() -> collections::string::String`, so it was a typo!

correct is `.fold(String::new(), |a, b| a.push_string(b.as_slice()));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 problems:

1. `String::new` is missing a `()` and should be `String::new()`
2. You have to returns a new state from the fold closure, `push_str` returns `()`.
3. You have to make the state mutable so you can use `push_str` on it.

---

```
fn main() {
  let nums = vec![1i,2,3];

  let strings = nums.iter()
  .map(|n| n.to_string())
  .fold(String::new(), |mut a, b| {
        a.push_str(b.as_slice());
        a
    });

  assert_eq!("123", strings.as_slice());
}
```

Comment: thanks! one question: are there performance differences between str.push_str(other) and str + other ?

Comment: @le_me: yes, with using `+` there is a new string allocated for every addition